# Is "sb." a commonly accepted abbreviation? What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

What does *sb.* mean? I keep seeing it certain posters' questions and I'm not sure what it's supposed to stand for — the word *something*, my initial guess, doesn't have a 'b' in it. So my questions are: Is it a known abbreviation? What does it mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*sb.* is used as abbreviation for substantive, which grammarians use as a basic term form for noun. This is an old practice from the Latin days. *n* is used to denote proper nouns in such cases.

For example, in "What does “pull sb. out of the hat” mean?", sb. is used as a placeholder for a noun.

Comment: This is backed up by a Google Books search, only slightly more commonly than for *somebody*: http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&prmdo=1&tbm=bks&q=+substantive+sb&oq=+substantive+sb&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=9766l9766l0l1l1l0l0l0l0l0l0l

Comment: +1 The OED uses it this way as well.

Answer (score 12):

Could it just be the abbreviation of ***somebody*** ?  [Here](http://www.all-acronyms.com/cat/9/SB/Somebody/36166) is an official definition.

But there are also [many possible contenders](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/somebody).

**Edit**
In case your question refers to the previously submitted question ["what does pull *sb.* out of the hat mean ?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26879/what-does-pull-sb-out-of-the-hat-mean) then the answer is definitely "*somebody*".

For instance in my Oxford Phrasal Verbs Dictionary, I can read:

[image]

Comment: I've definitely seen it used for *somebody* in dictionaries, possibly without the period. You can see it used this way in Google Books results: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=somebody+sb&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=bks&ei=TYTcTZjeKIuGvAOvzIXCDw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=6&ved=0CA8Q_AUoBQ&prmdo=1